# Azure Function – Current Azure Resource Name

Tags: azure, azure-functions

If I am in an Azure Function that is a TimerTrigger how can I get the name of my deployed Azure Resource at runtime.

In an HttpTrigger you can simply do this:  `req.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri` and get something that gives a good "*as deployed*" runtime description.

In a Timer it is not as obvious as to how you would get your Azure Resource Name or Path while the TimerFuncton is executing.

I would like something similar to   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext which gives you the compile time Function info – but I am looking for some run-time info from the Running Azure Resource that is executing my TimerTrigger function.

My fallback is to HardCode my Azure Resource Name into an Environment variable and read that at run-time. Seems odd but will work.

Thank You Claudiu

**Here are some final notes about this:**

```
// Environment Variable Usage 
string res = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
//  WEBSITE_HOSTNAME is like "myAzureDeployedFuncName.azurewebsites.net" 
//  WEBSITE_HOSTNAME is like "localhost:7072" 
string res = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_SITE_NAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
//  WEBSITE_SITE_NAME is "myAzureDeployedFuncName" on Azure 
//  WEBSITE_SITE_NAME is not there in local debug function runtime 

// using AppSettings is not the same and usign the above GetEnvironmentVariable call 
string res = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WEBSITE_HOSTNAME"]; // not there for Settings interface
//  WEBSITE_HOSTNAME will be blank - it is not part of "Settings"
string res = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WEBSITE_SITE_NAME"]; 
//  WEBSITE_SITE_NAME is "myAzureDeployedFuncName" on Azure when using "settings" instead of Environment variable 
//  WEBSITE_SITE_NAME is not there in local debug function runtime 
// the above AppSettings are not the same as GetEnvironmentVariable behavior at runtime
```

**To Call "yourself" from a function app timer trigger this is what is useful ...**

WEBSITE_HOSTNAME =  myAzureDeployedFuncName.azurewebsites.net

```
Some Other potentially useful Env Vars:
// next one has scm in name
HTTP_HOST = myAzureDeployedFuncName.scm.azurewebsites.net
// slot help
APPSETTING_WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME = Production
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read from the "WEBSITE_SITE_NAME" environment variable.

You can find more useful variables if you go to Kudu: "https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml"

Comment: I actually used WEBSITE_HOSTNAME for my situation. Your help and suggestions were exactly what I needed to know.